# Disabling the Visual Basic background compiler in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

How do I disable the background compiler for Visual Basic in Visual Studio 2008?

For my sins, I have to work on a large VB.NET project and it often locks up for 20 seconds at a time whilst doing the *very helpful* background compilation which is **extremely** frustrating.

I'd rather work blind between compiles and be able to do some work.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no way to disable the background compiler.

Have you installed Visual Studio 2008 **SP1**.  There were several bugs we fixed in the RTM version of VS 2008 which can cause the IDE to hang under certain circumstances.

We take issues with the background compiler very seriously.  If you can give us a repro of the problem it will definitely be investigated.  If you can produce such a repro or even send us a memory dump when the IDE is locked please file a bug on Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio

A couple of other steps you can take.  Do you have any Add-ins installed in VS?  If so try uninstalling them 1 at a time.  I've seen several cases where 3rd party add-ins caused lock ups in the IDE which were completely unrelated to the C#/VB framework.

Comment: I have got VS fully updated. The only add-ins I have installed are Resharper, Gallio and Test-Driven.NET. I have tried running native as I had read about add-ins causing problems and still came across the same problem. I'm using MSTest against a .NETCF 3.5 solution to throw some more into the mix.

Comment: I will see if I can find a way to consistently reproduce it but I've only found it on this large solution and I don't think I'd be able to provide you with our source. How would I go about giving you a memory dump from when it's hanging?

Comment: Also, do you know what the reasoning behind not providing a way to disable the background compiler? I know it's useful most the time, but just being able to switch it off would be very useful for me right now.

Comment: @Garry, the majority of the IDE features depend on the result of the background compiler.  Turning it off would effectively disable the majority of the IDE.