# Why can't the compiler just compile my code as I type it?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, compiler-theory

Why can't the compiler just compile my code as I type it?

From the user's point of view, it could work as smoothly as syntax colouring does today. If you stop typing for long enough (maybe a couple of seconds) the compilation (not linking) would finish, and code errors would be identified using something like syntax colouring.

It's not like my 3GHz quad core monster computer was really busy doing something else. Why not let it compile all the time?

Comment: Maybe because when you have it someone will want to turn it off. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665747/disabling-the-vb-background-compiler-in-vs2008

Comment: What language are you using ? It's not uncommon for IDEs to compile on the fly nowadays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's exactly what the VB.NET code editor in Visual Studio does.

The advantage is much more accurate IntelliSense than C#. The disadvantage is that it wastes truly vast amounts of processor time and memory. :-(

Comment: It's only a waste if it _isn't_ being used.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet: it can make the user interface sluggish & interfere with background processes (i.e. other programs). It's not like SQL Server where you can set a limit on memory & CPU usage.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet: Unfortunately it is used up. There is a very obvious upper limit on the size and complexity of a VB.NET solution. By contrast, I have worked on C# solutions 20 times the size and have yet to reach a practical limit.

Answer (score 5):

It can. Or, to be more useful, the answer to this question depends on

1. What language
2. What degree of optimization you require
3. How annoyed you will be if you temporarily type something dumb, and the compiler compiles and injects the result into the binary your are debugging before you can fix it.

Some really strong optimizations would be very messy to mess with on the fly. On the other hand, a basic compilation, if there's no need to worry about assigning offsets for X86 instructions? Sure.

Answer (score 3):

Some IDEs do compile (or at least check syntax and some semantics) code as it is typed.  For example, I think Eclipse does it.  I think Visual Basic 6 (and maybe earlier versions) did this.

Comment: As far as I experienced, Eclipse (the JDT, at least) does syntax-checks when typing, but the actual compilation (i.e. producing of class files) is only done when saving a file. (This could have changed in the last years, though.)

Answer (score 3):

Note sure what IDE you're using, but that's how VB.NET works.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not well-versed in compilers or the methods by which code is converted to IL and machine language, etc. But even so I can see how altering my program by one flow control statement can completely invalidate the work a compiler has done up to that point. By adding or changing a single line of code, entire portions of a program may become obsolete, unused, or in some other way require re-evaluation.

I think I'd rather save those CPU cycles for distributed.net or SETI @ Home instead of constantly recompiling my code as I alter it.

Answer (score 0):

That totally depend on the language.

Languages that have context-independent syntaxes "could" pre-compile expressions once typed. However, compilation of such languages project is always fast, so why use the cpu when you can batch quickly the work when the code is ready?

Other languages, like infamously C++, are context-dependent. In most cases, the compiler can't understand an expression without having already read the whole code before the expression. It's really really hard to parse and that's why we have error checking before compilation only now (in VS2010 and other recent ide). In this case it looks like impossible to implement the feature you're asking for.

That said, I'm not a specialist at all. That's all I know about it.

Answer (score 0):

Even interpreted languages like PHP have support for this in the Komodo editor. I'm sure there's many more editors out there that support this for almost any language.